# What's a good way to store this relation so I can answer queries of this form efficiently?

Tags: database, language-agnostic

Excuse me if I get a little mathy for a second:

> I have two **sets**, X and Y, and a many-to-many **relation** ℜ ⊆ X✗Y.
>
> - For all x ∈ X, let xℜ = { y | (x,y) ∈ ℜ } ⊆ Y, the subset of Y associated with x by ℜ.
> - For all y ∈ Y, let ℜy = { x | (x,y) ∈ ℜ } ⊆ X, the subset of X associated with y by ℜ.
>
> Define a **query** as a set of subsets of Y, Q ⊆ ℘(Y).
>
> Let the **image** of the query be the union of the subsets in Q:
>
> ```
> image(Q) = Uq∈Q q
> ```
>
> Say an element of X x **satisifies** a query Q if for all q ∈ Q, q ∩ xℜ ≠ ∅, that is if all subsets in Q overlap with the subset of Y associated with x.
>
> Define **evidence** of satisfaction of an element x of a query Q such that:
>
> ```
> evidence(x,Q) = xℜ ∩ image(Q)
> ```
>
> That is, the parts of Y that are associated with x and were used to match some part of Q. This could be used to verify whether x satisfies Q.

My question is how should I store my relation ℜ so that I can efficiently report which x∈X satisfy queries, and preferably report evidence of satisfaction?

The relation isn't overly huge, as csv it's only about 6GB.  I've got a couple ideas, neither of which I'm particularly happy with:

1. I could store { (x, xℜ) | ∀ x∈X } just in a flat file, then do O(|X||Q||Y|) work checking each x to see if it satisfies the query.  This could be parallelized, but feels wrong.
2. I could store ℜ in a DB table indexed on Y, retrieve { (y, ℜy) | ∀ y∈image(Q) }, then invert it to get { (x, evidence(x,Q)) | ∀ x s.t. evidence(x,Q) ≠ ∅ }, then check just that to find the x that satisfy Q and the evidence.  This seems a little better, but I feel like inverting it myself might be doing something I could ask my RDBMS to do.

How could I be doing this better?

Comment: This smells like homework. Unless you work in a higher-education math department as a research fellow, I can't see a real problem being couched in these terms :-)

Comment: paxdiablo: it's actually work, I just rephrased it to get rid of all the context of what exactly X and Y are, since they're overly specific to my job.  Consider if you have an arbitrary boolean combination of value ranges, e.g. "find me all x that (have a y in [0,10]) AND ((have a y in [11,20]) OR (have a y in [31,40]))".  Does that sound more real world to you? :)

Comment: Yes. Still too complex for me this early in the morning but at least the headaches from the original symbols have disappeared :-)

Comment: @rampion . . . I'm going to agree with paxdiablo's comment.  This is really too abstract for me to think about how to solve it.  If you decide to, ask another question with some real world details.

Comment: Gordon Linoff: Your marketing department is curious about customer shopping habits as they correspond with the calendar, and would like to be able to search the purchase records with queries like "Find me all the customers that: (made a purchase in December) AND ((made a purchase in July) OR (made a purchase in February))". X is your set of customers, Y is your set of sale dates, and &real; is your set of purchases.  Better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think #2 is the way to go.  Also, if Q can be represented in CNF you can use several queries plus INTERSECT to get the RDBMS to do some of the heavy lifting.  (Similarly with DNF and UNION.)

This also looks a bit a you want a "inverse index", which some RDBMS have support for.  X = set of documents, Y = set of words, q = set of words matching the glob "a*c".

HTH